# "Incompatible sample format 's16' for codec 'pcm_s24le', auto-selecting format 's32'" error in audio conversion using avconv

Tags: avconv

I use the command

`avconv -y -i input_file -acodec pcm_s24le -r 24 -ar 48000 output_file`

to extract audio from videos. With Ubuntu 10.04 the command run succesfully, but with Ubuntu 12.04 I receive the error

> Incompatible sample format 's16' for codec 'pcm_s24le', auto-selecting format 's32'

How can I solve?

Answer (score 1):

pcm_s24le has a [bit depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_bit_depth) of 24; it appears that your input audio has a bit depth of 16. Use pcm_s16le instead.

That said, using raw pcm audio (presumably in a .wav container) is way overkill, in terms of file size, unless you're doing waveform editing. Using

```
avconv input.file -vn -c:a copy output.file
```

would probably get you the best results. You gain nothing (well, nothing relevant to a modern computer) from converting the audio to pcm.

Comment: Not sure I understand the "gain nothing by using pcm" statement- if the user needs pcm audio (as input to an application that requires pcm audio for example) then the user "gains everything" by converting it to the format they require. Furthermore, the poster may need 24 bit depth for a reason... if so, this doesn't seem to answer the question.